# Laravel how to echo selected a value in a dropdown using blade when updating a specific resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I want to echo the selected value when I edit a specific resource in my table. When I edit the specific resource it should display the current data in my dropdown but in the real scenario it displays the first one on the list which is wrong. So how can I echo the selected value in the options of the dropdown using blade in laravel?

Here is some sample of my code in the **view** below

```
<!-- Shows Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('show_id', 'Shows:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('show_id', $shows, $shows, ['class' => 'form-control input-md','required'])!!}
</div>

{{-- {{ $channelshows->channel->name }} --}}
<!-- Client Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('channel_id', 'Channels:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('channel_id', $channel, $channel, ['class' => 'form-control input-md','required'])!!}
</div>
<!-- Submit Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    <a href="{!! route('admin.channelshows.index') !!}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

and here is the code in my **controller** below.

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $channelshows = $this->channelshowsRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        $shows =  Show::pluck('name', 'id');
        $channel = Channel::pluck('name', 'id');

        if (empty($channelshows)) {
            Flash::error('Assigned show not found');

            return redirect(route('admin.channelshows.index'));
        }

        return view('admin-dashboard.channelshows.edit', compact('shows', $shows), compact('channel', $channel))->with('channelshows', $channelshows);
    }
```

Everything here works fine even if I updated the specific resource. I just want to auto populate or select the current value of the resource that I will update because when I edit the specific resource it shows the first one on the list.

Am I going to use an @if statement in blade? But how can I do it using the blade template in my select form. Can somebody help me?

Appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

Open form:

```
{{ Form::model($service, array('route' => array('services.update', $service->id))) }}
```

Select form field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('Related Agreement') }}
    {{ Form::select('agreement', $agreementsList, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Please select ...')) }}
</div>
```

In Controller:

```
$agreementsList = Agreement::all()->sortBy('name', SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

(Include this when passing data to your view)

Comment: I tried it but it just sort the list from the dropdown it didn't select the current value of the specific resource

Comment: {!! Form::model($channelshows, ['route' => ['admin.channelshows.update', $channelshows->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!} like this

Comment: Did you change it to {!! Form::select('channel_id', $channel, null, ['class' => 'form-control input-md','required'])!!}

Comment: oops I just got a wrong spelling sorry for that. But thanks for the help! Sorry to bother for that. Appreciated it! It worked!

Comment: Thank you so much!